# When is Rep(U_q(g)) invariant under q -> -q and why?

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, monoidal-categories

Since this is a question about quantum groups, let me first fix notation.  In this question I use the conventions from [this paper of Sawin](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0308281.pdf). (That particular paper conveniently lists in the introduction which other sources use the same conventions and which don't.  In particular, its q agrees with Chari & Pressley's q and Lusztig's v.)

Let's look at the category of finite dimensional representations $\mathrm{Rep}(U_q(\mathfrak{g}))$ as a pivotal tensor category.  This category always a symmetry where $\mathrm{Rep}(U_q(\mathfrak{g})) \cong \mathrm{Rep}(U_{q^{-1}}(\mathfrak{g}))$. (This follows from looking at the idempotent version of $U_q$ where the symmetry is clear, as Tony Licata pointed out to me.)  However, sometimes there's an additional symmetry where $\mathrm{Rep}(U_q(\mathfrak{g})) \cong \mathrm{Rep}(U_{-q}(\mathfrak{g}))$.  In particular, I think I checked that all the rank two $\mathfrak{g}$ have this property (though $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ does not!).

My question is for which $\mathfrak{g}$ is $\mathrm{Rep}(U_q(\mathfrak{g})) \cong \mathrm{Rep}(U_{-q}(\mathfrak{g}))$ and where does the equivalence come from?  (Please note that I'm not requiring the equivalence to respect the braiding!)

One necessary condition is that the quantum dimensions of all irreps need to be even (as Laurent polynomials), which is the same thing as saying that $\rho$ lies in the root lattice.

Comment: I don't know if the conventions match yours, but Temperley–Lieb with the circle valued at $\delta = -q^2 - q^{-2}$ is invariant us a monoidal category under $q \mapsto -q$ (of course, since the monoidal category only depends on $q$ via $\delta$), and even as a braided category (via the natural isomorphism that acts by $-1$ on the defining object), but not as a pivotal category.

Comment: With the "usual" conventions the dimension of the 2d rep of $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ is $q+q^{−1}$. Your formula has two changes. There's a variable $s$ with $s^L=q$ where $L$ is the index of the root lattice in the weight lattice (so $L=2$ for $\mathfrak{sl}_2$).  You need this $s$ to write down the braiding.  Your q is s, which explains the appearance of $q^2$ in your formula. The minus sign is coming because TL is not the "usual" pivotal structure (since it's real instead of quaternionic).  (The latter point is not important since  changing piv. str. won't affect whether Rep is symmetric.)